# Mutt PGP Error: "Could not decrypt PGP message" & "Could not copy message" on Ubuntu machine but works on macOS machine

Tags: macos, ubuntu, encryption, pgp

Configuration files are **identical** on both machines since they are shared from a cloud drive.

Messages sent as a test to myself from the Ubuntu machine 'can' be decrypted and read on the macOS machine in mutt with no problems. Also, both machines sending to themselves work.

The problem is decrypting the messages on the Ubuntu machine sent from the macOS.

The Ubuntu machine has a GnugPG version which is a little older (2 years) than the macOS machine but both are above version 2.1 which saw some changes from previous versions.

I'm not using gpgme or its gpg-agent in the configuration files since I had issues with it a) defaulting to s/mime instead of PGP, b) not accepting self-signed X509 certs.

**Pure PGP config**

**MUTT ERROR MSG**

On selecting a message in mutt's message index, I get the following:

```
Invoking PGP ...
Could not decrypt PGP message
Could not copy message
```

**QUESTION**

1. Is this a GnuPG backward compatibility issue?
2. Can this be resolved and how?

**Version Details**

```
macOS:
$ gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.3.4
libgcrypt 1.10.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GNU GPL-3.0-or-later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Home: /Users/tonybarganski/.gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, ELG, DSA, ECDH, ECDSA, EDDSA
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
        CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
AEAD: EAX, OCB
Hash: SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2

---
Mutt 2.2.1 (2022-02-19)
Copyright (C) 1996-2022 Michael R. Elkins and others.

Compile options:
-DOMAIN
+DEBUG
-HOMESPOOL  +USE_SETGID  +USE_DOTLOCK  +DL_STANDALONE  +USE_FCNTL  -USE_FLOCK
+USE_POP  +USE_IMAP  +USE_SMTP  
+USE_SSL_OPENSSL  -USE_SSL_GNUTLS  +USE_SASL  -USE_GSASL  +USE_GSS  +HAVE_GETADDRINFO
+HAVE_REGCOMP  -USE_GNU_REGEX  
+HAVE_COLOR  +HAVE_START_COLOR  +HAVE_TYPEAHEAD  +HAVE_BKGDSET
+HAVE_CURS_SET  +HAVE_META  +HAVE_RESIZETERM  +HAVE_FUTIMENS  
+CRYPT_BACKEND_CLASSIC_PGP  +CRYPT_BACKEND_CLASSIC_SMIME  +CRYPT_BACKEND_GPGME
-EXACT_ADDRESS  -SUN_ATTACHMENT  
+ENABLE_NLS  -LOCALES_HACK  +HAVE_WC_FUNCS  +HAVE_LANGINFO_CODESET  +HAVE_LANGINFO_YESEXPR
+HAVE_ICONV  -ICONV_NONTRANS  -HAVE_LIBIDN  -HAVE_LIBIDN2  +HAVE_GETSID  +USE_HCACHE  
+USE_SIDEBAR  -USE_COMPRESSED  -USE_INOTIFY  
-ISPELL

Ubuntu20.04
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.19
libgcrypt 1.8.5
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Home: /home/tony/.gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, ELG, DSA, ECDH, ECDSA, EDDSA
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
        CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2

---
Mutt 1.13.2 (2019-12-18)
Copyright (C) 1996-2016 Michael R. Elkins and others.
Mutt comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; for details type `mutt -vv'.
Mutt is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; type `mutt -vv' for details.

System: Linux 5.13.0-35-generic (x86_64)
ncurses: ncurses 6.2.20200212 (compiled with 6.2)
libidn: 1.33 (compiled with 1.33)
hcache backend: tokyocabinet 1.4.48

Compiler:
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:hsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-9/README.Bugs --enable- languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,gm2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-9 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux- gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-     nls --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-  vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --      disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-           targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-9-HskZEa/gcc-9-9.3.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,hsa --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-     gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)
```